# Passing variable from header to screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, variables, header

For my study I am working on a react native project, but I'm stuck.

My structure is as follows:

```
MyApp
- Components (folder)
    -+ Header.js
    -+ Navigationbar.js
- Screens (folder)
    -+ Home.js
```

The Header.js looks as follows:

```
 export default function HeaderComponent() {
  const [
    selectedIndex,
    setSelectedIndex
  ] = React.useState(0);

  return (  
    <View>    
      <View style={style.header}>
        <Image //logo extracted from '../assets/logo.png'
            source={require('../assets/logo.png')} 
            style={style.image}/>
        <SearchBar //searchbar to search with the required props
            platform='default'
            containerStyle={style.searchbar}
            inputContainerStyle={style.searchbarInput}
            inputStyle={style.inputText}
          placeholder="Search here..."
          lightTheme
          round
        />
      </View>
      <View style={style.threeButtons}>
        <ButtonGroup
          containerStyle= {style.buttonContainer}
          buttonStyle={{ width: 60 }}
          buttonContainerStyle={style.buttonContainerStyle}
          textStyle={style.textStyle}
          selectedTextStyle={style.textStyle}
          innerBorderStyle={{color: '#EBEBEB'}}
          buttons={[
            "A-Z",
            "Highest",
            "Sport",
          ]}
          onPress={selectedIdx =>
          setSelectedIndex(selectedIdx)
          }
          selectedButtonStyle={style.selectedButtonStyle}
          selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
    );
}
```

And the Home.js file looks like:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    //this 'SafeAreaView' is required to render it safe on the screen, within the margins
    <SafeAreaView style={style.container}> 
       
        <HeaderComponent/>
      
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I want to pass the selectedIndex from Header.js to Home.js, so I can render text based on the tab that is selected (0, 1 or 2)
How do I do this? Is this the right method, but am I missing something. Or do I have to do it different?

Comment: Hi, You can create one service which will cater  between these components, or you can also  make use of ```Context``` by using ```Providers``` and ```Consumer``` to pass component.

Comment: Hi! Can you maybe explain this a bit more. I am relatively new to react native

Comment: Please have a look at this link [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
[Passing data between component](https://nipunadilhara.medium.com/passing-data-between-different-components-using-react-c8e27319ee69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Home.js and HeaderComponent have parent child relationship you can achieve what you want by "Lifting the state up". i.e rather than having useState in HeaderComponent you can have it in Home and pass the setSelectedIndex fn to the HeaderComponent as params.

```
 
export default function Home() {

const [
    selectedIndex,
    setSelectedIndex
  ] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>  
        <HeaderComponent selectedIndex={selectedIndex} setSelectedIndex={setSelectedIndex}/> 
     </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

```
export default function HeaderComponent({selectedIndex,
    setSelectedIndex}) {

  return (
{/* Your existing code   */}

 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems so easy, but didn't think of myself. Thank you!